# when i set the token in header in angularjs generating error in nodejs server?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

Error is:

```
 Possibly unhandled Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:344:11)
    at ServerResponse.res.set.res.header
```

1.all nodejs services working fine before set the token in header.

2.after set the token in header in angularjs creating that error in nodejs server.

my angularjs code is :

```
menu.factory('allServs', function ($q, $http,$cookieStore) {
propDetails:function (property_id) {

            var req = {
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/v1/xxxxxxx/'+xxxxxxx
              }

            if($cookieStore.get('userDetails')){
                req.headers = {
                    "authorization": $cookieStore.get('userDetails').token
                }
            }
            var deferred = $q.defer(),
                httpPromise = $http(req);
            httpPromise.then(function (response) {
                alert("response"+JSON.stringify(response));
                deferred.resolve(response);
            }, function (error) {
                alert("error"+JSON.stringify(error));
                console.error(error);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
}
```

3.In nodejs ,webservice token is getting ,decoding is fine and getting the response details but the problem is last line  at the time of return json data.

```
 app.get('/v1/xxxxxxx/:xxxxx',middlewares.requireLogin,function(req, res) {

    core.property.getProjectGroup(options, function (result) {

       return res.send({
                     result:result
                     });
                 });

    });
```

1. middlewares.requireLogin(token verify process) is working fine.
2. I solved that error by using this line  res.status(200).send().In that process in client its showing success code is 400.
3. so how can i solve that one. i want to get the data and status code as 200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling res.send() or res.end() twice somewhere in your code. Kindly check with the middleware, or other places with the response object if it calls a function that sends out an HTTP response BEFORE your last res.send() that you intended.

Comment: thanq @jekk for the rply, no i did not  repeated that line in any where of that particular service and middlewares.

Comment: ya ,thanq @jekk, i repeated two times next() in middle ware

Comment: Glad to have helped @SimhaChalam